# Using an InputBox modify the rows a ListBox displays on a UserForm

Tags: vba, excel

Let me preface this by saying that I am extremely new to VBA within Excel. My grasp may far exceed my capabilities.

I am currently struggling with returning specific data to a ListBox on a UserForm within Excel. Currently my code allows me to:

1. Filter a table within Excel, showing only rows containing the value "FALSE".
2. Add only the visible information into the ListBox.
3. Unfilter the table, showing all data to the user if required.

Code as below:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

With Sheet1
        ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:= _
        "FALSE"
End With

With ListBox1
    For Each oneCell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1[Plate ID]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        .AddItem CStr(oneCell.Value)
    Next oneCell
End With

With Sheet1
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3
End With

End Sub
```

What I'm after is step "2a", as it were, I require user input to determine the amount of data that they require. For example, and Input box that requests the number of rows of information they need. So if they input "5" into the field, it only returns 5 rows of data, not the whole data set.

The data set itself will be a set number of columns, yet the number of rows will grow over time as more information is added.

Any help with my query would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: PS. `With Sheet1` followed by `Activesheet.List....` ? Use one or the other. Preferably the `With Sheet1` to avoid `Activesheet` altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I'll remove the ActiveSheet component and stick with With Sheet, if I understand correctly I will be leaving the ListObjects component behind and simply removing ActiveSheet. from the start of the line?

Comment: In **this** case, where you're only using it once within each `With`, I'd be inclined to remove the `With / End With` altogether and just use `Sheet1.ListObj....`

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are after something like:

```
Dim rowlimit As Long
rowlimit = InputBox("Limit to how many rows?", "Limit")

With ListBox1
    For Each oneCell In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("Table1[Plate ID]").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        If .ListCount < rowlimit Then .AddItem CStr(oneCell.Value)
    Next oneCell
End With
```